# adjectival/adverbial grammar issue relating to "undisturbed"

Tags: descriptive-grammar

In the sentence "The blackbird was singing undisturbed on the outskirts of the wood" Could the word "undisturbed" be seen as both adjectival (qualifying "blackbird") as well as adverbial, (qualifying "singing")?

Comment: Hello Chris. I would say that it was adverbial rather than adjectival since it follows immediately after the verb. For 'undisturbed' to be adjectival it would need to be placed much closer to the noun, for instance "The undisturbed blackbird was singing on the edge of the wood". Also I don't think that a modifier _can_ perform both as an adjective and an adverb at the same time. If you placed 'undisturbed' between the noun and the verb it would need to be parenthetical which would make it refer to the noun. That is "The blackbird, undisturbed, was singing next to the wood"

Comment: I haven't posted that as an answer because a better qualified contributor might tell me I'm talking rubbish.